# I would like to insert into a table using a select query; the select query has an auto-increment field and multiple records

Tags: mysql

I know that you can use:

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_name = 'myTable'
AND table_schema = 'myDatabase'
```

if I am inserting one row at a time

but this will generate an error of Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY' if the select query returns multiple records

```
INSERT INTO myTable SELECT (SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = 'myTable' AND table_schema = 'myDatabase') AS Customer_ID,  Customer FROM myTable2 WHERE Customer LIKE '%Tech%'
```

Comment: As long as the select query returns multiple **unique** values, the insert should not fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much easier:

```
INSERT INTO myTable (Customer) SELECT Customer FROM myTable2 WHERE Customer LIKE '%Tech%'
```

:-)

Edit (Explanation): That's the true sense of AUTO_INCREMENT, you could simply leave it out and it gets an unused number. I think you could also give NULL as value, which would be translated to "next free value".

Nevertheless with @variables you can also easily create line numbers and the like, but that's kept for more interesting questions.

Comment: I tried to avoid that because my actual table has so many fields not just "Customer" but I guess that is the way to go.

Comment: Oh, then try the NULL.

Comment: @alkallali: sooner or later it's better to have the fields explicitely, it makes deploying much easier when the table changes.

Comment: the NULL option worked perfectly. thanks @flaschenpost